# How to get single data based on ID in react firestore v9?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to get single user data based on using firestore query. Recently, firebase got update to v9 so, i tried to modify query but it's not working may be I am doing something wrong. Here its what i am trying fetch single user based on id.

```
const id = useParams();
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onSnapshot(
      collection(db, "users", where("id", "==", id)),
      (snapShot) => {
        snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data());
        });
       
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
  }, [id]);
```

Collections screenshot
[image]

Comment: Are you referring to that document ID because I cannot see any ID field in document? If yes then you can use `doc(db, "users", id)` –

Answer (score 1):

You have to construct your query like this, [see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-9_1):

```js
const collectionQuery = query(
  collection(db, 'users'),
  where('id', '==', id),
);

const unsub = onSnapshot(collectionQuery, (snapshot) => {
  ...
})
```

Edit:

Judging from your attached screenshot, you might mean the ID of the document. In this case you can just get the document directly, without a query:

```js
const docRef = doc(db, "users", id);
const snapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
```

Comment: tried this way but it is not working. Here is code :- useEffect(() => {
    const singleUser = query(
      collection(db, "users"),
      where("id", "array-contains", id)
    );
    console.log(singleUser);
    const unsub = onSnapshot(singleUser, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
      });
    });

    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
  }, [id]);

Comment: Sorry,  updated the answer - your `where` clause is `==` not `array-contains`. My bad. Nonetheless, why isn't it working? Do you get an error?

Comment: Earlier I tried with that way only using "==" but I am not getting data. Getting this in console dc {converter: null, _query: Ce, type: 'query', firestore: Rc}. Didn't had any issue earlier but due to update in firebase v9 so, i am getting all these issue

Comment: Then your `where` clause doesn't match anything. Impossible to say without knowing how your data model looks like. The query executes, but `snapshot.size` is probably 0.

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the question

Comment: You don't have a property `id` in the document - then why do you query for it? Of course it's empty. You could query for `info`, `contact`, etc.

Comment: Ok so I am able to add the data but id property is not getting add. but that should added by default right while adding the data into firestore. I am just adding the data this way  await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        ...data,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      });

Comment: Your question is about _getting_ data, not _adding_ data. It's hard to answer a question when the target keeps moving.

Comment: No, I am saying but first I need to add the data that I am able to do. Then after I need the data based on Id but unfortunate id property is not adding collection while adding the data that's reason I am not getting data based on id

Comment: [Consult the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

Comment: Is there any other query to get the data based on document ID ? I am basically trying this version    db.collection("contacts")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then((contact) => {
        dispatch(getContact({ ...contact.data() }));
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error)); for updatd firebase v9

Comment: Anyway I found work around. Thanks for ur support